# Task Wait in For Loop C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, foreach, task, wait

I'm reading a file and wants to process 10 lines at a time.

This only works if I'm processing < 10 lines. For loop just continues and doesn't wait for the first 10 tasks to complete.

Please advise.

Below is my code :

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int lctr = 0;
  var tasks = new List<Task>();
  foreach (string s in lines)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
      continue;

    lctr++;
    tasks = new List<Task>();
    if (lctr < 11)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(lctr + " - " + s);
      tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => processThis(s)));
    }
    else
    {                        
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting ...");
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
  }
  if (tasks.Count > 0)
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());        
 }
```

Comment: `tasks` will always be empty when you `WaitAll` on it since you reassign an empty list to it before the `if`.

Comment: Also you'll want to reset `lctr` after each batch of 10 otherwise you will never again enter you `lctr < 11` condition.

Comment: Why do you want to use Tasks here at all? Nothing asynchronous is happening. Is `processThis` async?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Process 10 items in a batch in parallel? Why are you waiting between batches?

Comment: Two problemes: you're reseting task for each linge and you're not setting lctr to zero every 10 lines.

Comment: Use [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netcore-3.1) or Or [`Enumerble.AsParallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: What is the type of the variable `lines`?

Comment: If `processThis` is CPU bound work, you could use the `Parallel.ForEach()`, because your method is not async.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "Please Advise" it gives me wide latitude to try and help. Here are my suggestions and I hope you find them "useful":

Q: "I'm reading a file and wants to process 10 lines at a time."

A: Before spawning any tasks, enqueue your test list into groups of 10 strings (and a final group that might be partial if, say, the list is 25 string long).

Here is a method to do the first part:

```
    // Short-running method that queues up strings in batches of 10 or less
    private static Queue<List<string>> enqueueBatchesOf10orLess(List<string> testData)
    {
        Queue<List<string>> batchesOfUpTo10 = new Queue<List<string>>();
        List<string> singleBatchOfUpTo10 = new List<string>(); ;
        for (int count = 0; count < testData.Count; count++)
        {
            if ((count % 10) == 0) 
            {
                if(count != 0)  // Skip the very first time
                {
                    batchesOfUpTo10.Enqueue(singleBatchOfUpTo10);
                    singleBatchOfUpTo10 = new List<string>();
                }
            }
            singleBatchOfUpTo10.Add(testData[count]);
        }
        // Leftover batch of less-than-10
        if(singleBatchOfUpTo10.Count != 0)
        {
            batchesOfUpTo10.Enqueue(singleBatchOfUpTo10);
        }
        return batchesOfUpTo10;
    }
```

Next, it appears you want to process those batches concurrently (implying that there might be some processing time that justifies doing this). Here is how you pass your "batches of 10 or less" in and receive a Task in return.

```
    private static Task processBatch(Queue<List<string>> batches)
    {            
        return Task.Run(() => // Return task that processes batch of 10 or less
        {
            var batch = batches.Dequeue();
            foreach (var singleString in batch)
            {
                processThis(singleString);
            }
        });
    }
```

...where...

```
    private static void processThis(string s)
    {
        Task.Delay(100).Wait(); // Simulate long-running string processing
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

To test this out:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Make some test data
        List<string> testData = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) testData.Add((i + 1).ToString());

        Queue<List<string>> batchesOf10OrLess = enqueueBatchesOf10orLess(testData);

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < batchesOf10OrLess.Count; i++)
        {
            // Pass in the queue of batches and get a Task in return.
            tasks.Add(processBatch(batchesOf10OrLess));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The test data is NOT in order.");
        Console.WriteLine("This is proof the tasks are running concurrently");
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        // Pause
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Here's what we get:

```
The test data is NOT in order.
This is proof the tasks are running concurrently
1
21
11
2
12
22
3
23
13
4
14
24
5
25
15
6
16
7
17
8
18
19
9
10
20
```

If you like [download](https://github.com/IVSoftware/wait-all-tasks/blob/master/wait-all-tasks/Program.cs) this sample from GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestions, I'll give it a try in a couple of days since I'll be offline.